# Connecting R to Oracle DB without admin

Tags: python, r, oracle, roracle

I need an R script that allows me to connect to an Oracle DB without having to install anything needing admin powers, and preferrably nothing at all apart from package downloads. In python the following code works, I believe because it uses the cx_Oracle module as a portable driver. What would be a good R alternative?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import sys
host = "xxx.intra"
database = "mydb"
user = "usr"
password = "pw"
def get_oracle_engine(host, database, user, password):
   return sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{password}@{host}:1521/?service_name={database}".format(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password))
engine=get_oracle_engine(host, database, user, password)    
pd.read_sql_table("mytable", engine, schema= mydb,index.cols="id1")
```

I managed to install ROracle using [the CRAN instructions](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL) but I keep getting the `ORA-12154 TNS: cound not resolve the connect identifier specified` when using:

```
library(ROracle)
con= DBI::dbconnect(dbDriver("Oracle"), user= user, password=password, host=host, dbname=database, port="1521")
```

By the way `dbDriver("Oracle")` returns

```
Driver name : Oracle (OCI) 
Driver version: 1.3-1
Client version: 12.1.0.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try code like:

  ```
  library(DBI)
  library(ROracle)
  drv <- Oracle()
  con <- dbConnect(drv, 'cj', 'welcome', 'localhost:1521/orclpdb1')
  dbGetQuery(con,"select count(*) from dual")
  ```

  The connect string components are related to the `{host}:1521/?service_name` values you used with SQLAlchemy.  Use a TNS alias or Easy Connect String, the same as other C based Oracle drivers, e.g. https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings
- The current ROracle code is at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html  There are some packaging glitches with uploading to CRAN and the CRAN maintainers haven't been responsive about resolving them.
- ROracle still needs Oracle Client libraries such as from Oracle Instant Client.

Comment: I'd never have thought it, but using `localhost:1521/orclpdb1` works while listing the parameters `user`, `port`, etc does not. Could you please explain why you think that is so?